# Solving PDE with three variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve a PDE for $\zeta(x,t,u)=\zeta\left(t,x-S_t(u)\right)$, but am having a bit of trouble.

The PDE is given by:

\begin{align*} &\frac{x}{2}\tau'(t)\zeta_x(x,t,u) + \tau(t)\zeta_t(x,t,u)+ \sigma(t,u)\left(\frac{x}{2}\tau'(t) + \tau(t)\left(\mu_0(t) - \frac{\partial S_t(u)}{\partial t}\right)\right)\zeta_u(x,t,u) = 0, \end{align*}

the final solution should be $\zeta(x,t,u)=\zeta\left(x-S_t(u)+M_0(t)\right)$, where $S_t(u)=\int \frac{1}{\sigma(t,u)}du$ and $M_0(t)=\int\mu_0(t)dt$.

I tried to use the method of characteristics
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{\frac{x}{2}\tau ^{\prime }(t)}=\frac{dt}{\tau (t)}=\frac{du}{%
\sigma (t,u)\left[ \frac{x}{2}\tau ^{\prime }(t)+\tau (t)\left( \mu _{0}(t)-%
\frac{\partial S_{t}(u)}{\partial t}\right) \right] }=\frac{d\zeta }{0},
\end{equation*}%
but
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d\zeta }{0}\Longrightarrow \zeta =\zeta \left( C_{1},C_{2}\right) .
\end{equation*}%
while the first ration leads to%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\tau ^{\prime }(t)}{\tau (t)}dt\Longrightarrow
C_{1}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\tau (t)}}.
\end{equation*}%
For the second ration%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dt}{\tau (t)}=\frac{du}{\sigma (t,u)\left[ \frac{x}{2}\tau ^{\prime
}(t)+\tau (t)\left( \mu _{0}(t)-\frac{\partial S_{t}(u)}{\partial t}\right) %
\right] },
\end{equation*}%
we can write that%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\left[ \frac{x}{2}\tau ^{\prime }(t)+\tau (t)\left( \mu _{0}(t)-\frac{%
\partial S_{t}(u)}{\partial t}\right) \right] }{\tau (t)}dt=\frac{du}{\sigma
(t,u)},
\end{equation*}%
that is%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\frac{x}{2}\tau ^{\prime }(t)}{\tau (t)}+\frac{\tau (t)\mu _{0}(t)}{%
\tau (t)}-\frac{\tau (t)\frac{\partial S_{t}(u)}{\partial t}}{\tau (t)}dt=%
\frac{du}{\sigma (t,u)}
\end{equation*}%
we have that $\int \frac{du}{\sigma (t,u)}=S_{t}(u)$ and $,$ $M_{0}(t)=\int
\mu _{0}(t)dt,$ then%
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{2}\ln \tau (t)+M_{0}(t)-S_{t}(u)=S_{t}(u).
\end{equation*}

But I got stuck here.

Comment: You missed a ratio $\frac{d \zeta}{0} \implies \zeta = f(C_{1}, C_{2})$ where $C_{1}, C_{2}$ are two characteristic curves. Next, the first ratio implies $$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\tau'(t)}{\tau(t)} dt \implies \ln x = \frac{1}{2} \ln \tau + \ln C_{1} \implies \frac{x}{\sqrt{\tau(t)}} = C_{1}$$ You can then use the ratios in $dt$ and $du$ to solve for the second characteristic $C_{2}$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thanks for your time. Actually, I did that after but still did not reach the required solution!

Comment: I reached that $$\zeta(C_1,C_2)=\zeta\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t} },\frac{x}{2}\ln{t}-2S_t(u)+M_0(t)\right).$$

Comment: Why would you expect solutions to be independent of $\tau$? I assume $\tau$ is given.

Comment: @BobTerrell I didn't expect it, but the solution is expressed as I wrote before

Comment: Thats close, though I think you mean the characteristics are $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{\color{red}{\tau}(t)}}, \quad \frac{x}{2} \ln \color{red}{\tau}(t) - 2 S_{t}(u) + M_{0}(t)$$ and there actually shouldn't be a $\ln \tau$ term, nor should there be a multiple of $2$ on the $S_{t}(u)$ term in the $C_{2}$ characteristic i.e $$C_{2} = x - S_{t}(u) + M_{0}(t)$$ Perhaps you could post your working to get the second characteristic?

Comment: Anyway, if you differentiate the result $$\zeta = \zeta_{0}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\tau(t)}}, x - S_{t}(u) + M_{0}(t) \right)$$ and substitute them into the PDE you find will find there are explicit expressions for $M_{0}(t)$ and $S_{t}(u)$ that are required for the PDE to hold. What are those expressions?

Comment: @MatthewCassell I added it above, could you have a look, please?

Comment: Your integration doesn't work because $x = x(t)$ is a function of $t$. You need to replace the $x$ with it's expression in $t$ i.e $x \tau'(t)/2 = C_{1} \sqrt{\tau(t)} \tau'(t)/2$, then do the integration then go back to the $x$ coordinate.